# php Find matching word from a string with array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, match

I need to find 1 word from a string, like:

```
  $row['keyword'] = "hello my name is jon";
```

If the word "text" matches to one word from `$row['keyword']` so do something..

I  try this, but i think there is a better way:

```
       foreach($rows as $row) 
        { 
            if (strpos($row['keyword'],"text") !== false) {
               // do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: Put `text` inside quotes. Besides that, its a good way to test. Why look for more? you will always find alternatives but for what.

Comment: Looks fine to me and I doubt you'd find a much better solution.

Comment: yes, you're way is just fine and efficient, you don't need anything else. if you want to match "jon" and "john" (or more complex things) you may prefer using `preg_match("#joh?n)n#")`, but that's not required for your example

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you've provided looks fine, it's probably the best solution for the job you want to do already.  The only question I have regarding it is "Do you want to run whatever the do-something code is for every haystack that contains the needle, or just for the first one you find?".  If it's the latter, then you should add a break; after the do-something code.

If you're trying to performance-tune your code, then this really isn't the sort of thing you need to worry about.  Any change you make to the code as is would be a [micro-optimization](/questions/tagged/micro-optimization) at best and would have negligible impact for a disproportionate amount of work.  If your code performs okay then don't worry about it.  If it is suffering performance issues then you need to investigate exactly where the bottlenecks are and why they're occurring, and optimizing those parts of your script. When optimizing it's important to find where you'll gain the maximum benefit from the effort needed.

The biggest and best optimization choice you can make is selecting the right algorithm for what you want to do, everything else is implementation details.

Answer (score -1):

there are many alternatives and ways but depend on your requirement. You can check this link https://www.php.net/strstr and "See Also" section. Moreover, You can simplified your code rather than using array and loop. Please see the following:

```
$str = 'hello my name is jon';
if(strpos($str, 'text')!='')
 echo "do something";
else
 echo "do something";
```

Comment: This is already what the OP's code is doing, except also iterating over an array of haystacks.

Comment: but strpos is to find position no? i need to find the word in a string

Comment: actually my main intention was to show other relate functions what could be used. anyway :(

Comment: strpos returns false if it can't find the string, so it's the right function to use.